# How to put text over a game by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to put text on screen over a game like "Need For Speed"?
Is "DirectPython" helpful for this solution?

A short sample code will be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you try clarify what you're trying to achieve a bit better. It's hard to help when we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to show some text over a game. for example show clock counting down.

Comment: You want to use something like this [Game Overlay SDK](https://github.com/Andrey1994/game_overlay_sdk). I doubt DirectPython has hooking capabilities. What is it you want to achieve?

Answer (score -2):

Are you aware that you cannot modify the "code" that the game runs. All the commercial programs do not provide the source code to run their creation, only compiled and encrypted versions.

You can wrap the execution of the game like so:

```
proc Wrap { game_starter_path } {

execute game_starter_path ; 
hold till game running ; 
show time ;
```

}

Have fun

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer. What is the snippet of code?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you answer a bad question, you should at least make it a very good answer so that the Q&A is worth keeping around.